# Disable session for Report Viewer web control in ASP.Net

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm new to working with SSRS, and I have a problem in which I am deploying SSRS setup into a load balance environment with strict requirements that sessions cannot be used. I just need to know the options on how best to do this, any help on a starting point would be much appreciated.

-Thanks

Comment: There are two sessions in play. You web application may or may not have sessions and ssrs may or may not have sessions. There is a flag you can set on the rsviewer control to disable or create a new session per request, however that only relates to sessions pulled up for your reports on ssrs. Your applications sessions are controlled separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn `SessionState` Off in the project web.config, but if you do so, you have to enable `ReportViewerServerConnection`:

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251661.aspx for more details.